# android:visibility="gone" does not clear up the space on certain devices:

Tags: android, android-layout, visibility

I have the following portion of layout in one of my layouts:

```
    .....
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/llGameInformation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtnVolume"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_button_selector"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_button_sound" />
        <!--app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_button_sound"-->

        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGameCardText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/cl_game_screen_card_name_text_color"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            tools:text="card name"
            android:gravity="center"
            autofit:minTextSize="22dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.GothamBook"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgBtnShowCards"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgBtnVolume"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtnShowCards"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_button_selector"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_button_view"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        ads:adSize="FLUID"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
....
```

As you can understand from it's name **llBottom** is a `LinearLayout` that should be at the bottom of the screen, and it is. In it I have a `RelativeLayout` that contains several views and under it I placed an `AdView`.

I start the AdView with visibility="gone" and I intend to display it based on sever preferences.

**The problem is:** While this behaves as intended on Nexus 5X the AdView is removed and **llGameInformation** is the most lower ViewGroup in the layout, on Galaxy devices on the other side AdView is not visible but still takes up the space, so the **llGameInformation** has an empty space bellow it.

Does someone know what would be the right way to handle this? so no empty space will be left on all devices?

Comment: have you tried programmatically adding and removing the view to the RelativeLayout as and when you need it rather than using visibility?

Comment: are you using emulator or real device?

Comment: @BIW, No didn't... firstly I wanted to explore all my layout possibilities to resolve this issue... what more it works on some of the devices.

Comment: @Pooya, I'm using real devices.

Comment: What exact Android version is it not working on? Also, just out of interest, if you temporarily replace the `AdView` in your layout file with a standard component, say a `TextView`, is that component hidden as expected?

Comment: @clownba0t: 6.0.1 is not working. Didn't tried to replace it yet with any other component... will do that soon and update.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your AdView with `FrameLayout` and set its viability to `gone`, it could be that the view change it's visibility on it's own.

If you like to dive deeper or if previous not working, you can write a costume `FrameLayout` and see if somebody actually try to change its visibility that is not you, in such case you will be able to debug it and block it, as its your view.

There is no way somebody will be able to change your `FrameLayout` viability if you don't like it to.